# "Dink on their record", except "Dink" appears to be the wrong word?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

I was talking to some coworkers and we were talking about some negative publicity on a company. I wanted to say "looks like another dink on their record", but I realized I was not sure if that was the correct word.

I double-checked the dictionary, and couldn't find a definition that matched my meaning:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dink

I'm thinking something like "scratch" or "dent" or "negative mark".

Like if you were driving down a tight alley and "dinked" the side of your car?
Am I just completely making up this definition? Not sure where I learned to use "dink" that way. I think maybe from Counterstrike where you get hit in the head it's a "dink"?

so question is: Is dink the right word to use in this context? if not, is there a word that sounds like dink that i'm potentially conflating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @user888379 for answering in comments, the word I was thinking of was "Ding"

**Ding:**
criticize, injure, or penalize (someone).
"agents who stayed on a call too long got dinged"

i was just mixing up Dink and Ding in my head

Comment: I've heard "dink" used in this sense.  Just based on the sound, a "dink" is a smaller dent than a "ding".

Comment: Glad to help out. You can accept your own answer, by the way.